# Keystone Tutorial: cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: node.js, keystonejs

I was following the tutorial on starting KeystoneJS from scratch. But when I got to the second part of the tutorial, creating data models, I got this error:

```
Error thrown for request: /keystone/
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at IndexRoute (/root/websie/node_modules/keystone/admin/server/routes/index.js:39:16)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/root/websie/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/root/websie/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/root/websie/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/root/websie/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /root/websie/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/root/websie/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/root/websie/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /root/websie/node_modules/keystone/admin/server/app/createDynamicRouter.js:26:3
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/root/websie/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/root/websie/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /root/websie/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/root/websie/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/root/websie/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at handleUploadedFiles (/root/websie/node_modules/keystone/lib/uploads.js:6:54)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/root/websie/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
GET /keystone/ 500 8.835 ms
```

Since I'm new to Keystone JS, I don't quite know if this problem is with the code itself or the database.

Things to consider:

- This is run on a linux environment
- MongoDB is freshly installed

These are all the files so far:

keystone.js

```
const keystone = require('keystone')

keystone.init({
        'cookie secret': 'SECRET KEY',
        'name' : 'theproject',
        'user model' : 'User',
        'auth' : 'true',
        'auto update' : 'true',
});

keystone.import('models');

keystone.start();
```

User.js:

```
const keystone = require('keystone');

var User = new keystone.List('User');

User.add({
    displayName: { type: String },
    password: { type: keystone.Field.Types.Password },
    email: { type: keystone.Field.Types.Email, unique: true },
})

User.schema.virtual('canAccessKeystone').get(function () {
    return true;
});

User.defaultColumns = 'id, displayName, email';

User.register();
```

Comment: Please mark an answer if it resolved your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your User model doesn't have an "id" attribute. So when you set your User.defaultColumns to "id" it doesn't find anything.

All models do however have an "_id" attribute.

I would just remove "id" from your default columns and move forward.

```
User.defaultColumns = 'displayName, email';
```

If that doesn't fix it you might be requesting the id elsewhere.

Comment: where else could i be requesting the id?

Comment: could be in your routes or even the pug file that you are trying to render. Is there an id in your keystone.js file?